# Directly passing the selected images to another function

Tags: c++, mysql, opencv, image-processing

I am using mysql as database for face recognition application. I am storing images into the database in the training phase and at the testing phase I will select all these images back and compare with the incoming image. Since I am using mysql, in the database it store images as blob images. So when I select it back I need to write it into separate image files using a file pointer(this should be done for each images in the DB).

```
    sprintf(temp,"SELECT data FROM ima1 WHERE id=%d",i);
    sprintf(filename,"Gen_Image%d.jpeg",i);
    fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
    mysql_query(conn, temp);
    result = mysql_store_result(conn);      
    row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
    lengths = mysql_fetch_lengths(result);
    fwrite(row[0], lengths[0], 1, fp);
```

But after selecting image, this will be stored into the current directory. For using that images I need to read the directory again.But I need to use selected images directly from that function. **Can we pass the selected images into another function(without read it again from the directory)?If yes please show me an example**

```
I tried 'imdecode'function:
std::vector<std::string> vectordata;
vectordata.push_back(row[0]);//(row[0]);
 cv::Mat data_mat(vectordata,true);
 cv::Mat image(cv::imdecode(data_mat,1));
 cout<<"Height: " << image.rows <<" Width: "<<image.cols<<endl;
```

It is not showing any error, but it is selecting the images with zero size,that means it is  not selecting the images.

Comment: So you need to store in compressed format?

Comment: In the database it will be in binary form, after selecting I need to pass it to another function. So we need to convert it into 'Mat' format, that I explained above. But still it's not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for encode and decode, working fine for me, you may need to use `uchar` to store data.

```
Mat src=imread("src.jpg",1);
vector<uchar> buf;
imencode(".jpg",src,buf);

Mat dst=imdecode(buf,1);
imshow("src",src);
imshow("dst",dst);
```

Comment: Here source image is in 'row' we need to convert it into 'Mat' format,then only it will work.The method which I mentioned above is for converting data in the 'row' to 'Mat'.But the problem is after conversion and all, images is having zero width and height(no images are loading). So we can't give this as input to 'imencode' function. It is showing the error like: Unknown error code -10 (Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported)) in throwOnEror,

Comment: Does `row` represent continuance BGR,BGR pixel data?

Comment: row is MYSQL_ROW type.

Comment: Actually I am little confused about your question like 'Can we pass the selected images into another function(without read it again from the directory)?If yes please show me an example' so you don’t want to store in mysql?

Comment: I am talking about images which are taken from the database(selected image). I need to pass it directly to another function with out reading it again from the directory.

Comment: Ok, so  for passing the image to new function, we need to convert to Mat first, for that we need to know how you store the image in database, is that BGR,BGR row data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51006/discussion-between-haris-and-user3228547)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image into a 2d/1d vector and save RGB pixel values of vector in data base instead of passing whole image and then extract these values and make a mat of these values i think this will work for you.